# Running a Thread inside a thread, " Class exception error "

Tags: java, multithreading, class, methods, queue

I am having a run method which tries to override another run method. But its not happening because I am getting a "Class not found Exception" before it passed on to run method.

Here´s my class with run method

How could I get this over ride the run method.

the class which I have to call in order to execute.

```
    public abstract class MessageProcessor implements Runnable {
private Collection<KpiMessage> fetchedMessages;
private Connection dbConnection;
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
private Collection<KpiMessage> outgoingQueue;


public KpiMsg804 MessageProcessor(Collection<KpiMessage> outgoingQueue, Connection
 dbConnection){
    this.outgoingQueue = outgoingQueue;
    this.dbConnection = dbConnection;
    return (KpiMsg804) fetchedMessages;
}

    public Collection<KamMessage> generate(Collection<KamMessage> outgoingQueue)
   {
    while(true){
        try {

            while (rs.next()) {
                KamMessage filedClass = convertRecordsetToPojo(rs);
                outgoingQueue.add(filedClass);

            }

            for (KamMessage pojoClass : outgoingQueue) {
                KamMsg804 updatedValue = createKamMsg804(pojoClass);
                System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getSequence());
                System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getTableName());
                System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getAction());
                System.out.print(" " + updatedValue.getKeyInfo1());
                System.out.print(" " + updatedValue.getKeyInfo2());
                System.out.println(" " + pojoClass.getEntryTime());
            }
            return outgoingQueue;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Show us the complete stack trace.

Comment: Have you defined a `MessageProcessor` class?

Comment: Do you have the MessageProcessor class in the Class path?

Comment: @Madhusuthanan Seetharaman Yes it is in the class path ,,, my task is to run the seond thread while the main thread is sleeping for 3 seconds, but my execution doesn't even peeps into message processor class... catch Exception e1...

Comment: @pap ya I have declared pls check my update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are creating a default-visibility field inside a class, and not overriding the `run()` method. Just stick to:

```
MessageProcessor processor = new MessageProcessor() {
  @Override
  final public void run() {
    MessageProcessor(outgoingQueue).generate(outgoingQueue);                    
  }
};
```

And remove the outer `MessageProcessor` declaration.

I made a subset of your code:

```
public class PollingSynchronizer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MessageProcessor message = new MessageProcessor() {
      MessageProcessor message = new MessageProcessor() {
        public void run() {
          System.out.println("new run");
        }
      };
    };

    new Thread(message).start();
  }
}

class MessageProcessor implements Runnable {
  public void run() { System.out.println("old run"); }
}
```

Which will print `old run` because the first `MessageProcessor::run()` it is not really being overwritten.